# MYSQL - Query somando 8 tabelas idênticas

Tags: mysql, query

Boa tarde, sou bem novo em MYSQL, basicamente estou aprendendo em buscas na rede, mas surgiu uma questão que não consegui solucionar.

Possuo cerca de 6 tabelas, em cada uma eu tenho 10 lançamentos fixos e idênticos no campo ID e TIPO, os quais não são alterados, sendo possível alterar apenas os valores desses campos.

Exemplo:

```
Dep1
ID  TIPO    VALOR1  VALOR2  VALOR3  VALOR4
1   Camisa  10        20       30   40
2   Calça   15        25       35   45
3   Blusa   3          2       9    25

Dep2
ID  TIPO    VALOR1  VALOR2  VALOR3  VALOR4
1   Camisa     5      10       15   3
2   Calça     30       5       5    10
3   Blusa      9       1       5    5

Dep3
ID  TIPO    VALOR1  VALOR2  VALOR3  VALOR4
1   Camisa     5       10     15    3
2   Calça      30      5       5    10
3   Blusa      9       1       5    5

E assim por diante....
```

A ideia é conseguir montar uma query para somar todos os valores por item, de cada tabela, obtendo o seguinte resultado:

```
    deptotal (id, tipo, total1,total2,total3,total4,totalgeral)

ID  TIPO    TOTAL1  TOTAL2  TOTAL3  TOTAL4  VALORTOTAL
1   Camisa    20      40      60      46      166
2   Calça     75      35      45      65      220
3   Blusa     21       4      19      35      79
```

Tentei da seguinte forma, mas com um "query time" terrível, chegando a travar o servidor por alguns instantes:

```
    select 
    (dep1.id) as ID,
    (dep1.tipo) as TIPO,
    (dep1.valor1)+(dep2.valor1)+(dep3.valor1)+(dep4.valor1)+(dep5.valor1)+(dep6.valor1) as total1,
    (dep1.valor2)+(dep2.valor2)+(dep3.valor2)+(dep4.valor2)+(dep5.valor2)+(dep6.valor2) as total2,
    (dep1.valor3)+(dep2.valor3)+(dep3.valor3)+(dep4.valor3)+(dep5.valor3)+(dep6.valor3) as total3,
    (dep1.valor4)+(dep2.valor4)+(dep3.valor4)+(dep4.valor4)+(dep5.valor4)+(dep6.valor4) as total4,
(dep1.valor1)+(dep2.valor1)+(dep3.valor1)+(dep4.valor1)+(dep5.valor1)(dep6.valor1)+(dep1.valor2)+(dep2.valor2)+(dep3.valor2)+(dep4.valor2)(dep5.valor2)+(dep6.valor2)+  (dep1.valor3)+(dep2.valor3)+(dep3.valor3)+ (dep4.valor3)+(dep5.valor3)+(dep6.valor3)+(dep1.valor4)+(dep2.valor4)+ (dep3.valor4)+(dep4.valor4)+(dep5.valor4)+(dep6.valor4) as VALORTOTAL

    FROM
    dep1,dep2,dep3,dep4,dep5,dep6
    where (dep1.id = dep2.id = dep3.id = dep4.id = dep5.id = dep6.id)
```

Bom amigos, talvez a tabela tenha ficado bem confusa, mas ao final ficou funcional, apresentando problemas quando adicionei mais tabelas no banco de dados.

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda, abraço.

Comment: VOcê é que define o banco de dados? Por que não adiciona uma coluna "departamento" e usa uma tabela só?

Comment: eu defino apenas o ID, que refere-se á um codigo interno, e o TIPO, que é padrão, a ideia seria alterar apenas os valores.

Comment: Mas foi você que criou o sistema? Se sim qual o motivo de ter uma tabela para cada departamento, isso não faz sentido, e se precisar criar um novo departamento vai fazer o que, criar mais uma tabela?

Comment: eu criei, mas como falei, não tenho conhecimento no assunto e estou a base de procuras começando a aprender. Tentarei montar outra tabela da forma que vocês aconselharam

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se é a opção mais bonita mas acredito que se você utilizar um `UNION ALL`
na tabelas por exemplo;

```
SELECT juncao.ID,
       juncao.TIPO, 
       SUM(juncao.valor1) total1,
       SUM(juncao.valor2) total2,
       SUM(juncao.valor3) total3,
       SUM(juncao.valor4) total4,
       SUM(juncao.valor5) total5,
       SUM(juncao.valor1 + juncao.valor2 + juncao.valor3 + juncao.valor4 + juncao.valor5) totalgeral
FROM
     ((SELECT * FROM Dep1)
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT * FROM Dep2)    
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT * FROM Dep3)    
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT * FROM Dep4)    
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT * FROM Dep5)
     ) as juncao
GROUP BY juncao.ID,juncao.TIPO
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: em vez de union deve ser usado o union all, uma vez que duas tabelas podem ter registos exatamente iguais

Comment: Boa Observação, fiz a mudança sugerida.

Comment: funcionou, obrigado pela ajuda, mas pelo visto, conforme relataram acima, acho que estou pensando da forma errada, começarei do zero pra tentar fazer algo mais limpo. Muito obrigado.

Comment: infelizmente desse modo não é possivel criar uma view, senão estaria perfeito.